# Bohr frequency of an expectation value?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, frequency, hamiltonian, observables

Consider a two-state system with a Hamiltonian defined as

\begin{bmatrix}
E_1 &0 \\ 
0 & E_2
\end{bmatrix}

Another observable, $A$, is given (in the same basis) by

\begin{bmatrix}
0 &a \\ 
a & 0
\end{bmatrix}

where $a\in\mathbb{R}^+$.

The initial state of the system is $\lvert\psi(0)\rangle = \lvert a_1\rangle$, where $\lvert a_1\rangle$ is the eigenstate corresponding to the larger of the two possible eigenvalues of $A$. What is the frequency of oscillation (the Bohr frequency) of the expectation value of $A$?

I'm completely lost, as I don't understand what this question actually means. This problem is from a textbook in which I couldn't find any info from which it would be clear what this question means. Googling "Bohr frequency" doesn't seem to give much info either. I'd appreciate if someone could please clarify, preferably in detail, what one is supposed to do to solve this problem, and the exact meaning of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Heisenberg picture, one simply has
$$ A(t) = \exp(-Ht/i\hbar) A(0) \exp(+Ht/i\hbar) $$
The Hamiltonian 
$$ H = \frac{E_1+E_2}{2}\cdot {\bf 1} + \frac{E_1-E_2}{2} \cdot \sigma_z $$
while
$$ A(0) = a\sigma_x $$
The term in $H$ proportinal to ${\bf 1}$ cancels in $A(t)$ so we have
$$ A(t) = a\cdot \exp(-(E_1-E_2)t\sigma_z/2i\hbar) \sigma_x \exp(+(E_1-E_2)t\sigma_z/2i\hbar) $$
If interpreted as a spin, the exponential is the operator rotating by the angle $$ (E_1-E_2)t/\hbar,$$ and the factor of $1/2$ is already there because it's spin-1/2, and the conjugation is the right action of the operation on operators like $\sigma_x$, so the angular frequency with which $A(t)$ is oscillating is $\omega=(E_1-E_2)/\hbar$.

Comment: Can you please clarify what is $\sigma_z$?

Comment: It's the Pauli matrix https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices